# Creating Media items in Umbraco 6.x using the MediaService

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, umbraco6

I've been trying to create a media item and save the picture using teh MediaService with no success.

In simple terms, what I want to achieve is this:

1. Get the url of said image (which I do already). For example this: "[https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ad/D%C3%BClmen%2C_Alte_Brennerei_L%C3%B6hning_--*2015*--_8664-8.jpg/800px-D%C3%BClmen%2C_Alte_Brennerei_L%C3%B6hning_--*2015*--_8664-8.jpg](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ad/D%C3%BClmen%2C_Alte_Brennerei_L%C3%B6hning_--_2015_--_8664-8.jpg/800px-D%C3%BClmen%2C_Alte_Brennerei_L%C3%B6hning_--_2015_--_8664-8.jpg)"
2. Download said image
3. Save the image in the media folder, e.g. /media/1234124/image.jpg
4. Get the image location "/media/1234124/image.jpg"
5. Assign the image location to an image property on a node (fine if I could save the image).

All this is happening in a controller.

Tried using WebClient to download the image into byte[] variable and add it to the MemoryStream but it just doesn't like it.

Any help will be much appreciated

EDIT: Added some of the code. The commented ones are different things I tried and none worked. I was working on this one month ago, so not sure which one gave me the closest results. I remember the newImage.SetValue("umbracoFile", imageName, fileName); didn't like having 3 arguments but I read somewhere that it should accept them.

```html
var mediaService = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MediaService;
var mediaFolder = Umbraco.TypedMediaAtRoot().DescendantsOrSelf("Folder").Where(x => x.Name == "DailyMotion Video Thumbs").First();

.....

string thumbUrl = theVideo.thumbnail_120_url;
var indexOfLastSlash = thumbUrl.LastIndexOf("/");
string imageName = thumbUrl.Substring(indexOfLastSlash+1, thumbUrl.Length - indexOfLastSlash - 1);
                    
var newImage = mediaService.CreateMedia(String.Format("{0}_thumb", theVideo.id), mediaFolder.Id, "Image", 0);

//byte[] fileContents = null;

//try
//{
//    var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(theVideo.thumbnail_120_url);

//    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
//    {
//        using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
//        {
//            fileContents = sr.ReadToEnd();
//        };
//    };
//}
//catch (Exception e)
//{

//}

WebClient wc = new WebClient();
byte[] bytes = wc.DownloadData(theVideo.thumbnail_120_url);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);

//var tempImage = new Bitmap(ms);
//var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/media/dailymotionthumbs/" + newVideoNode.Id + "_" + imageName);
//tempImage.Save(path, ImageFormat.Png);

//FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
//var fileName = fileStream.Name;

//byte[] buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(fileContents)));
//System.IO.MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream(fileContents);

//newImage.SetValue("umbracoFile", imageName, fileName);

//mediaService.Save(newImage);

......
```

Comment: Show the code you are using.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas Added the image code.